# Need help updating a JSON payload with Go

Tags: json, go

I am a newbie and trying to create a Golang script that reads from one endpoint then updates some of the fields and posts to a different endpoint. The PUT request to the endpoint has this as a curl command.

```
curl -v \
     -X PUT -H 'X-Api-Key:{Key}' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' url/{id} \
     -d '{ "name" : "Somename", "type": "Sometype", "status" : "enabled"}'
```

I want to keep the same name and same type from the endpoint that I send the GET request, but I want to change status from enabled to disabled when posting to the other endpoint. So basically whatever results I get from the one endpoint will stay the same except the status that I need to change to disabled. Any example code will assist.

This is the code I have so far but it is just for reading the endpoint. So not sure how to join the two.

```
func main() {
   req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "URL", nil)
   req.Header.Set("X-Api-Key", <Key>)
   resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

   defer resp.Body.Close()
   body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

   var obj struct {
       Library []struct {
           Name     string `json:"name"`
           Type      string `json:”type”`
           Status      string `json:”status"`
       } `json:”library"`
   }

   if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &obj); err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   for _, app := range obj.Library {
       fmt.Println(app.Name, app.Type, app.Status)
   }
}
```

Comment: Show the code that you tried so far and describe any problems that you had.  If you have not started on this, then see the [net/http](https://godoc.org/net/http) and [encoding/json](https://godoc.org/encoding/json) packages. These packages have everything that you need to solve this problem.

Comment: @CeriseLimón see edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just need to loop over the Library items, updating the status and doing the http put requests.

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
for _, item := range obj.Library {
  item.Status = "disabled"
  bs, err := json.Marshal(item)
  // check err
  req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "url", bytes.NewBuffer(bs)) 
  // check err
  res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
  // check err
  // check res.StatusCode
}
```